# Can every closed differential form be expressed via constant coefficients?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-forms, linear-pde, tensor-decomposition

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$ dimensional manifold, and let $1 \le k < n$. Let $\omega \in \Omega^k(M)$ be a closed $k$-form on $M$.

> Let $p \in M$. Do there exist coordinates around $p$, such that $\omega=a_{i_1i_2\dots i_k}dx^{i_1} \wedge dx^{i_2} \dots \wedge dx^{i_k}$, where $a_{i_1i_2\dots i_k}$ are *constants*?

That is, I ask whether every closed differential form be locally expressed via constant coefficients.

**Edit:**

I forgot to require that $\omega$ should be **everywhere non-zero**. Otherwise, as [mentioned by Paulo Mourão](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3284776/104576), one can take $xdx$ on $M=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What happens to $\omega = x\,dx\wedge dy + z\,dz\wedge dw$ on $\Bbb R^4 - \{x=z=0\}$? Oh, or to $\omega = y\,dx+x\,dy$ on $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$? It's fine away from the axes, but ...

Comment: Ah, no, the $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$ example works fine locally.

Comment: Indeed, for a nowhere-vanishing $1$-form, we can apply the Frobenius Theorem and compute in the coordinate system it provides.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me generalize somewhat Jack Lee's answer. Assume $V,W$ are finite dimensional real vector spaces and let $\mu \in \Lambda^k(V)^{*}, \nu \in \Lambda^k(W)^{*}$ be two $k$-alternating forms on $V$ and $W$ respectably. Let's say that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are **equivalent** if there exists an isomorphism $T \colon V \rightarrow W$ such that for all $v_1, \dots, v_k \in V$ we have
$$ \nu(Tv_1, \dots, Tv_k) = \mu(v_1, \dots, v_k). $$
In order words, $\nu$ and $\mu$ are equivalent if $T^{*}(\nu) = \mu$. By functoriality of the pullback, this is an equivalence relation.

**Claim:** Let $\omega$ be a $k$-form on a manifold $M^n$ and let $p \in M$. A necessary condition for the existence of a coordinate system around $p$ in which $\omega$ has constant coefficients is that there exists a neighrhood $U$ of $p$ in which $\omega_{p'}$ is equivalent to $\omega_p$ for all $p' \in U$.

**Proof:** If $\varphi \colon V \rightarrow U \subseteq M$ is a coordinate system in which $\omega$ has constant coefficients, then $\varphi^{*}(\omega|_{V}) = \sum_{I} a_I dx^{I}$. Set $\omega_0 = \sum_{I} a_I dx^{I} \in \Lambda^k(\mathbb{R}^n)^{*}$ and let $p' = \varphi(q') \in U$. Then $d\varphi|_{q'} \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow T_{p'}M$ is a linear isomorphism which gives an equivalence between $\omega_{p'}$ and $\omega_0$. Since $p' \in U$ was arbitrary, $\omega_{p}$ is also equivalent to $\omega_0$ and so $\omega_p$ and $\omega_{p'}$ are equivalent.

When $k \in \{1, 2, n-2, n-1, n\}$, one can classify explicitly when two $k$-forms are equivalent using the rank. For the other cases and general $n$, it seems to be an open problem (you asked about it before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845555/classifying-the-orbits-of-the-natural-textglv-action-on-the-exterior-powe)) but having constant rank is definitely not sufficient. For some examples showing that constant rank or local equivalence is not sufficient, see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.02553.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! (1) I guess a natural question would now be whether or not the "equivalence condition" is sufficient for a form to be a 'constant coefficients' form. I guess that the answer is negative. (2) Are you sure that 'constant rank' does not imply equivalence (on the pointwise linear algebra level)? (3) Even if this is true, I am not sure if this claim automatically lifts to the manifold setting, but again this is another matter...

Comment: @AsafShachar: I've added a link with examples showing that neither constant rank nor the equivalence condition is sufficient. A relevant keyword is "multisymplectic geometry" in which one studies closed non-degenerate $k$-forms. When $k = 2$, Darboux's theorem shows that such forms can be represented locally with constant coefficients. When $k  > 2$, this is generally not true.

Answer (score 8):

There is a nontrivial necessary condition -- $\omega$ must have ***constant rank***.

The ***rank*** of differential form is defined as follows: a $k$-form is said to be ***decomposable*** if it can be written locally as a wedge product of $1$-forms. Every $k$-form can be written locally as a sum of decomposable $k$-forms, and the ***rank*** of a $k$-form at a point is defined as the minimum number of decomposable terms in any such representation. See [this Wikipedia article for more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Rank_of_a_k-vector).

A constant-coefficient form obviously has constant rank, so that's a necessary condition for $\omega$ to be expressed as a constant-coefficient form in some coordinates. To see that this condition is stronger than nowhere-vanishing in general, consider the following  closed $2$-form on $\mathbb R^4$, with coordinates $(w,x,y,z)$:
$$
\omega = w\, dw\wedge dx + dy \wedge dz.
$$
This is nowhere vanishing, and it has rank $2$ wherever $w\ne 0$, but on the $w=0$ hyperplane it has rank $1$. Thus there are no coordinates in a neighborhood of the origin that will make it constant-coefficient.

For $1$-forms, constant rank just means either identically zero or nowhere-vanishing. Obviously the zero form has a constant-coefficient representation, and as @TedShifrin pointed out in a comment, the Frobenius theorem shows that a nowhere-vanishing closed $1$-form has such a representation in a neighborhood of each point. Thus the constant-rank condition is sufficient for $1$-forms.

For $2$-forms, constant rank is equivalent to the matrix of the form having constant rank in any coordinates. In this case, here's a proof that the constant-rank condition is sufficient: Suppose $\omega$ is a closed $2$-form with constant rank $p$. By the Poincaré lemma, in a neighborhood of each point there is a $1$-form $\theta$ such that $d\theta = \omega$. Then because $d\theta$ has constant rank, the the [generalized Darboux theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem) implies that there are local coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^{n-p},y^1,\dots,y^p)$ in which $\theta$ is given by
$$
\theta = x^1\,dy^1 + \dots + x^p\,dy^p,
$$
and therefore $\omega$ has the constant-coefficient expression
$$ 
\omega = dx^1\wedge dy^1 + \dots + dx^p \wedge dy^p.
$$

I'm not sure about sufficiency for forms of degree higher than $2$, but I suspect it's true in that case as well. I would consult the book *Exterior Differential Systems* by Bryant et al.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you don't have such coordinates around $0$ for $\omega=xdx$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice observation, which I missed. If I understood correctly your intention, the essence here is that a constant coefficients form which vanishes at a point, must vanish at the entire neighbourhood. (and you chose a form which vanishes at a single point, hence cannot be a 'constant coefficients form'). I wonder if this is the only obstruction. (I have edited the question to mention this).